# Swift macOS label Gradient Text

Tags: swift, macos, label, gradient, nstextfield

I have a label in a macOS project which when connected becomes an `NSTextField`. I want to make the text have a gradient overlay.

I have some code to do this with an iOS `UIButton`, but for this project I keep getting the error that `NSView` has no such thing called mask and I don't know what to mask it to

```
extension NSTextField {
func applyGradientText(colors: [CGColor]) {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.colors = colors
    layer?.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    let overlayView = NSView(frame: bounds)
    overlayView.layer?.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

overlayView has nothing called mask, and I don't know what to mask to

```
    overlayView.mask = SOMETHING

    addSubview(overlayView)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `wantsLayer = true` on the `NSTextField` as it doesn't have a layer by default. Then just set `layer?.mask = gradient` and the label will show where gradient is `CGColor.clear`.

```
label.applyGradientText(colors: [CGColor.black, CGColor.clear])

extension NSTextField {
    func applyGradientText(colors: [CGColor]) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.colors = colors
        wantsLayer = true
        layer?.mask = gradient
    }
}
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Hey @Leongard thanks for the answer, but the problem is that the layer doesn't have a variable called mask

Comment: @Levi K Really? label doesn't have mask but label.layer should. It's a plain CALayer. Does my extension above give you an error on layer?.mask = gradient? Works for me.

Comment: @Leongard It did the last time I tried, but I just cleaned it, so I'll try again and let you know